# Save a backend form with custom field in OctoberCMS

Tags: octobercms

I am working on a backend form with a custom textarea field. This field should be parsed after saving the form and the parsed data will be inserted to another model.

Here is what I am doing for the model.

```
class SampleOne extends Model
{
   public function beforeSave()
   {
      // here I removed the custom field, and go ahead to save it
      ..... 
      $this->setRawAttributes(.....);
   }

   public function afterSave()
   {
      // here I am planning to parsed my custom field, and save mass data to another model.
      SampleTwo::insert($dataArray);
   }
}
```

Is it making sense or do I have better choice?